# It is given that $p = 2q+1$, and $p$ is a prime number. Prove that $(q!)^2 +(-1)^q$ is a multiple of $p$.

Tags: prime-numbers

It is given that $p = 2q+1$, and $p$ is a prime number. Prove that 
$$(q!)^2 +(-1)^q$$ is a multiple of $p$.

Attempt:

$q = \frac{p-1}{2}$

\begin{align}
\therefore (q!)^2 +(-1)^q &= \frac{1}{4} [(p-1)!]^2 +(-1)^q \\ &=\frac{1}{4} \left[\frac{p!}{p}\right]^2 +(-1)^q
\end{align}

The first part is clearly divisible by $p$. I dont know what to do with the $-1$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: $(p-1)!\neq p!-p$

Comment: Oh yes, division. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From $p=2q+1$, we get $q={\large{\frac{p-1}{2}}}$

At the start of your attempt, you made a serious error . . .

From $q={\large{\frac{p-1}{2}}}$, it follows that
$$q^2=\left({\small{\frac{1}{4}}}\right)(p-1)^2$$
but it doesn't follow that
$$(q!)^2=\left({\small{\frac{1}{4}}}\right)\Bigl((p-1)!\Bigr)^2$$

You made another error when you suggested that
$$\left(\frac{p!}{p}\right)^2$$
"is clearly divisible by $p$".$\;$It's definitely *not* divisible by $p$.

Starting over, you can argue as follows . . .

Applying Wilson's Theorem, we get
\begin{align*}
&(p-1)! \equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;p)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\bigl((1)(p-1)\bigr)
\bigl((2)(p-2)\bigr)
\cdots
\bigl((q)(p-q)\bigr)
 \equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;p)
 \\[4pt]
 \implies\;&
 \bigl((1)(-1)\bigr)
 \bigl((2)(-2)\bigr)
 \cdots
 \bigl((q)(-q)\bigr)
 \equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;p)
 \\[4pt]
 \implies\;&
(-1)^q(q!)^2
\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(-1)^{2q}(q!)^2
\equiv -(-1)^q\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
(q!)^2
\equiv -(-1)^q\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\[4pt]
 \implies\;&
(q!)^2+(-1)^q
\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;p)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: very nice solution

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By Wilson's theorem [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem ] $(p-1)!\equiv -1 \mod p$.